# java Thread safe for calling and caller methods

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have two methods A() and B(). I am calling method B() inside method A(). Method A() is synchronized (thread safe).

```
public synchronized A() {
     //some code
     B();
     //Some code
}

public B() {
    //some code
}
```

for thread safe in java Do I need to make method B() also synchronized. Please suggest.

Comment: Is `B()` a helper method which is only ever called from inside `A()`?  If so, then I see no reason to synchronize it.

Comment: make B() private and only call it from A() - then you don't need to make it synchronized. (btw: it's discouraged to name methods starting with a capital letter.)

Answer (score 0):

if `B()` is only called from inside `A()`, no need for synchronizing access to `B()`. Just make `B()` private so that it can not be called accidentally outside `A()`.

If `B()` can be called from outside of `A()`, then you have to use synchronization in `B()`.